# Как корректно реализовать чтение конкретных строк в Python

Tags: python, база-данных

Стоит задача брать по одной строке из файла 'a', искать их в 'b', и если есть записывать в 'c'.

Тут собственно несколько моментов:
1-й и самый главный: Как считать конкретную строку?

Я знаю, что файл a, и файл b будет следующего формата:

1. info:info
2. Каждая линия начинается с новой строки

Соответственно количество строк я могу посчитать по количеству ":" либо по количеству "\n" + 1, значит каждую новую строку я могу считывать по ее точному номеру.

Немного отклонимся от темы.
Алгоритм поиска был выбран такой:

```
word = #строка из a для проверки
with io.open('b.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        if word in line:
           print(line) #типо дебаг
           c.write(line+'\n')#пишем в c, и начинаем новую строку
           c.flush()#сброс данных
```

Для его корректно работы, очевидно нужно присваивать word значение строки из a. Тут то и вопрос, как мне взять конкретную строку из a?

Допустим что 'a' содержит такие строки:

```
mail1:name1
mail2:name2
mail3:name3
```

Есть какой-то запрос/команда чтобы например вызвать строку 2 (чтобы ее вызов выдавал `str(mail2:name2)`? какой-нибудь `a.readline(2)` (знаю что это не верная команда, пытаюсь передать суть.

Метод с `readlines()` не хочу реализовывать намеренно, потому что в файле a может быть 10 строк, а может и 10 000 строк. Хочу сделать скрипт максимально универсальным. Есть какие то модули внешние, или способы реализации подобного? Смотрел в интернете, ничего не нашел, хотя пытался по разному.

С `SQL` не дружу. Придется превращать текст в таблицу/бд? Нельзя просто прочитать условно строку(i) из a?

Comment: @Эникейщик Знаю про readline(), но так и не понял, как он выбирает строку для чтения? Я могу задать ему аргумент с номером конкретной строки? Либо он сам автоматом увеличивает номер строки на 1,  и это никак не изменить?

Comment: Я не совсем правильно понял вопрос, комментарий удалил. Посмотрите здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081836/reading-specific-lines-only-python

Comment: @Эникейщик видел этот способ, и пытался его интерпретировать под себя, но чет не вышло. Как мне его интерпретировать? Прошу прощения, но с for не дружу и его синтаксис в прицнипе понимаю трудно. Сейчас поясню

Comment: @Эникейщик я должен сделать так?: for i, line in enumerate(file): print(line) ? Так как у меня прямая последовательность 0-999 мне не нужны if с конкретным значением, так как if i == v (которое равно i ) будет всегда выполняться. Был бы рад еслибы пояснили такой момент

Comment: Можно обернуть все в функцию и передавать в нее номер строчки как аргумент.

Comment: Похоже на [XY-проблему](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/23044). Вы хотите `grep -Ff a b > c` реализовать на Питоне?

Answer (score 1):

Код по ссылке из коментария можно завернуть в функцию и передавать номер строки как аргумент:

```
def read_my_line(linenumber):
    with open("file") as fp:
        for i, line in enumerate(fp):
            if i == linenumber:
                return line
```

Для большей универсальность можно еще и имя файла сделать аргументом:

```
def read_my_line(filename, linenumber):
    with open(filename) as fp:
        for i, line in enumerate(fp):
            if i == linenumber:
                return line
```

Пример:

```
s = read_my_line("test.txt", 12)
```

Выдаст 12-ю строчку из файла test.txt в переменную `s`.

Но, конечно, чем больше файл, тем дольше будет делаться.

---

Или вот вариант с `linecache()` - [How to jump to a particular line in a huge text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620367/how-to-jump-to-a-particular-line-in-a-huge-text-file)

Comment: код работает как надо, огромное спасибо! Сейчас постараюсь интегрировать в программу. Еще раз благодарю.

Comment: Опять проблемка. Вот такой код (просто код с ответа) выдает такое: None, None, None. Это результат print(read_my_line('a.txt',1)), print(read_my_line('a.txt',2)), print(read_my_line('a.txt',3)). Что я опять делаю не так?

Comment: В файле только одна строчка или он пустой.

Comment: Действительно. Он каким то образом форматнулся. Уже сделал какой то вариант через linecache. В любом случае - спасибо за участие

Comment: Кстати, нумерация начинается с нуля (у первой строчки номер 0), поэтому это нужно учитывать при передаче аргументов или подправить код, чтобы из linenumber при обработке вычитать 1.

Comment: Да, знаю этот момент.